# How to on Ubuntu multiple-desktop have apps remain their popups localised

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, gnome, compiz

I've set up my Ubuntu desktop (Gnome/Compiz) to have 9 virtual desktops so I can keep my open applications organised. However, I've noticed that e.g. when Eclipse is downloading/installing plugins and I switch away to work on another desktop in the meantime, Eclipse pops up it's dialogs on the current active desktop, not the desktop it was launched on. Other apps seem to behave similarly.

How do I make launched applications to constrain their popups and dialog to the desktop they where launched on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You write a better window manager?

Sadly, though, I think this might simply be one of those gun+foot feature
interaction issues. I use Gnome/Openbox, and I have the same problem. I also
happen to know a *little* bit about how wm:s work, so I feel confident this is a snafu between popups appearing together with their parents, and what happens when a window is mapped/unmapped. (shown/not shown (for whatever reason, as opposed to iconify, other virtscreen, or whatever))

I would **love** to be proven wrong, but I think this could actually be a really bass-ackwards thing for the wm to solve, requiring somewhat surprising and underhanded trickery.